# php foreach loop a folder get files in its' subfolder

Tags: php, directory, subdirectory, file-exists

I have some `error_log.txt` files, create in `/var/www/html/log/'.date(Ymd).'/error_log.txt`, The folder table like this.

```
-log-
    |--20120825 -- error_log.txt
    |--20120826 -- 
    |--20120827 -- error_log.txt
    |--20120828 -- error_log.txt
```

How to make a `foreach loop` in folder which name as `log`, then get all the `subfolder name` and make a judgment if there has `error_log.txt` in this  `subfolder`?

As the `folder table` show, `20120826` have no `error_log.txt` in it, so do not print the `folder name`.

Finally I need get the folder name: `20120825, 20120827, 20120828`

```
$folder = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../log/';
foreach(glob($folder) as $subfolder){
  if(file_exists($subfolder.'/error_log.txt')){
    echo  $subfolder.'<br />'; //I get nothing.
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure your log folder is one level below the file that contains this code??? dirname(__FILE__) get the path of the file that contains the code, not where it executes when it is included. so if you include this file like this into index.php include "includes/bla.php" you will get the path the the includes folder, not the folder that contains index.php

Comment: @bkwint, yes. use @Yoshi's code, I get `$entry` as the filename like `/var/www/html/../log/20120828/error_log.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$folder = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../log/';
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder)) as $entry) {
  if ($entry->isFile()) {
    echo $entry, '<br />';
  }
}
```

Used in this way, you'll only get actual files. And if you don't like the iterator style, use:

```
$folder = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log/*';
foreach(glob($folder) as $subfolder){
  $path = $subfolder . '/error_log.txt';
  if (file_exists($path)) {
    echo basename($subfolder), '<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: this will get the final file name like `/var/www/html/../log/20120828/error_log.txt`, but I need get the `20120828`, and `isFile()` just make a judge if the folder has file in it. In fact, I will still restore other logs in the folder like `/var/www/html/../log/20120828/`. So I need `if(file_exists)`, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
$folder = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../log';


foreach(glob($folder.'/*') as $subfolder){
  if(file_exists($subfolder.'/error_log.txt')){
    echo  $subfolder.'<br />'; //You will get the folder name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also could use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

```
$folder = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../log/';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $subfolder){
  if(is_numeric($subfolder)){ // As your folder all use number, use `is_numeric` to remove sub folder '.' and '..'
    if(file_exists($folder.$subfolder.'/error_log.txt')){
      echo  $subfolder.'<br />';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1: I was going to give the same answer, `scandir` is the way to go!